Retrieve a delta of records when any related table timestamp passes the date supplied
I am trying to trigger a report from on a primary table when any relation has an updated timestamp greater than 5 minutes ago.
The updated timestamp of the related tables can differ from the primary or be null
primary_table
id(int), updated(timestamp)
relation table_one (one to many)
id(int), pid(int), updated(timestamp)
relation table_two (one to many)
id(int), pid(int), updated(timestamp)
Semi psuedo code below
The issue here is that the subquery fields t1_updated or t2_updated are not available in the where clause.
I tried switching the where to having but this turned out to be a very expensive query
I would love to be able to distil N number of related updated fields into one updated field on the primary that takes the max from the primary or relations if at all possible.
select
    p.id,
    p.updated,
    coalesce(
        (
            select max(updated) 
            from table_one t
            where t.pid = p.id
            group by  t.pid
        ), p.updated
    ) as t1_updated,
    coalesce(
        (
            select max(updated) 
            from table_two t 
            where t.pid = p.id
            group by  t.pid
        ), p.updated
    ) as t2_updated
from
    primary_table p
where (updated > '5 minutes ago' or t1_updated > '5 minutes ago' or t2_updated > '5 minutes ago')

any help appreciated

you need also to provide data and wanted result, so that we can help you

You may want to consider CTEs

This question is similar to: Unknown column in 'where clause' when using an alias for a subquery in MySQL. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

thanks @mustaccio put me on the right track there

Following the hint on CTEs from @mustaccio I went with this implementation
with last_updated as (
    select id as pid from primary_table where updated > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)
    union all select pid from table_one where updated > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)
    union all select pid from table_two where updated > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)
),
updated as (
    select distinct(pid) from last_updated l
)
select 
    up.pid as id
from updated up

Thanks everyone for taking a look
